# Execute on all files without corresponding extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

**How can I find and execute a program when the said file does not have a corresponding file?**

Example files:

```
/file1.c
/file1.h

/file2.c

/file3.c
/file3.hpp

/file4.c/unrelated.txt
```

`find / -type f -name '*.c' -exec my_program_here {} \;` executes on:

```
/file1.c
/file2.c
/file3.c
```

but I want to filter out those with a corresponding `.h` file. In the end, `my_program_here` should be run on:

```
/file2.c
/file3.c
```

In my case, **how can I filter out all results where `*.h` exists?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing a `sh` wrapper around `my_program_here` instead of running it directly.  For example:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec \
  sh -c '[ ! -e "${1%c}h" ] && my_program_here "$1"' find-sh {} \;
```

or (to fork sh only once and iterate over all the matching .c files):

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c \
  'for f; do
     [ ! -e "${f%c}h" ] && my_program_here "$f"
   done' find-sh {} +
```

These use shell's parameter expansion `%` "remove matching suffix" feature in order to check if there is a matching .h file for the current .c file being processed.  If there isn't, it executes my_program_here with the filename as the arg.

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcu/chap2.html

> `${parameter%word}`
>
> Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern. The word will be expanded to produce a
> pattern. The parameter expansion then will result in parameter, with the
> smallest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.

This feature is available in bash, ksh, and other posix-compatible bourne-like shells.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of the *rawhide* (*rh*) program used here (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide).

A shorter (but just as tricky) *rh* alternative:

```
rh -X 'my_program_here %S' 'f && "*.c" && !"n=%S; [ -f \"${n%%c}h\" ]".sh'
```

The `-X 'my_program_here %S'` is like GNU *find*'s `--execdir` which safely chdirs to the directory containing each matching file and `%S` refers to each file's basename (like *find*'s `{}`).

You could instead use `-x 'my_program_here %s'` which is like *find*'s `--exec` which unsafely refers to the full path to the matching file (`%s` like *find*'s `{}`).

The search criteria searches for files (`f`) named *.c (`"*.c"`) where the corresponding *.h file doesn't exist using a shell escape (`!"n=%S; [ -f \"${n%%c}h\" ]".sh`). Note that the double % (`%%`) isn't using the shell parameter expansion `${var%%suffix}`. It's just a quoted single `%` inside the shell escape string.

On Linux, the `-X` option can go after the search criteria.